# How to write a test for testing if a folder is readable / writable

Tags: perl, testing, perl-module

I wrote a module that checks a directory if it is writable or readable. 
But, how do I test it?

Usually, when writing a module you can write some tests for testing the features of the module. How can I create a directory, that is not writable by the test that actually created the module?

I imagine something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Temp qw/ tempdir /;

use Test::More tests => 5;
BEGIN { use_ok('My::DirCheck') };

my $readable_dir = tempdir();
my $check = My::DirCheck->new(directory => $readable_dir);

is($check->is_readable(), 1, 'temp dir is readable');

# FIXME: how to make it not readale?
isnt($check->is_readable(), 1, 'temp dir is not readable');


my $writable_dir = tempdir();

is($check->is_writeable(), 1, 'temp dir is writeable');

# FIXME: how to make it not writable?
isnt($check->is_writeable(), 1, 'temp dir is not writeable');
```

But how do I create a directory, make it e.g read-only and get rid of it afterwards?

Comment: `perldoc -f chmod` and `perldoc perlport`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `File::Temp`, try to use [`File::Path`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html), it allows you to choose a *mode* parameter that is able to set your [directories's permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Numeric_notation). Set mode to `0000` for a directory without read, write nor execution permissions.

Assuming it is from Perl core, it should be portable on most of OS.

Comment: Hm, I tried it, but it doesn't seem to work:

    # -- create a dir that cannot be read
    my ($non_readable_dir) = make_path($readable_dir . '/not-readable', {
     mode => 0000,
    });
    diag("non-readable test dir: $non_readable_dir");
    diag("readable? " . (-r $non_readable_dir));
    my $check2 = My::DirCheck->new(directory =>     $non_readable_dir);
    is($check2->is_readable(), 0, 'dir is not readable');